# How to merge arrays of objects while removing duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a requirement to compare the two object arrays and remove duplicate and merge them into a single one. 
I am kind of new to javascript/Typescript. I have read some blogs which are using Map, reduce,filter to do the job.
Is that the right approach?

However, I am wondering if I can create a map of it and the Map.ContainsKey or Map.getvalues();

In the real problem, ojects are quite huge, has several keys and even array has hundreds of records.

```
   [
    {
        Name: Roger
        Country : spain
    },
    {
        Name:Tiger
        Counry : USA
    },
    {
        Name: Micheal
        Country: USA
    },
]


[
    {
        Name: sachin
        Country : India
    },
    {
        Name:Roger
        Counry : Spain
    },
]

output 

[
    {
        Name: Roger
        Country : spain
    },
    {
        Name:Tiger
        Counry : USA
    },
    {
        Name: Micheal
        Country: USA
    },
    {
        Name: sachin
        Country : India
    }
]
```

Comment: what is a duplicate? same name or same name **and** same country?

Comment: here same name and same country. In real problem is a combination of fours keys.

Comment: So it should eliminate a whole object even if one value matches with the same key in the other array?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table for the wanted values as key and push the elements which do not have a flag in the hash table.

```js
var array1 = [{ Name: 'Roger', Country: 'Spain' }, { Name: 'Tiger', Counry: 'USA' }, { Name: 'Micheal', Country: 'USA' }],
    array2 = [{ Name: 'sachin', Country: 'India' }, { Name: 'Roger', Country: 'Spain' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [array1, array2].reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (o) {
            var key = ['Name', 'Country'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
            if (!hash[key]) {
                r.push(o);
                hash[key] = true;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's one possible solution:**

```
// Step 1, concat the two arrays together.
const allItems = items1.concat(items2);

// Step 2, map the above into an array of key/value entries.
const entries = allItems.map(o => [`${o.Name}:${o.Country}`, o]);

// Step 3, create a Map on the entries. De-duping happens here.
const map = new Map(entries);

// Step 4, extract the map's values back into an array.
const result = [...map.values()];
```

Some notes about this approach:

1. During the `concat()` in step 1, order matters! Items in `items2` take precedence over `items1`. In other words, items at the end of the `allItems` array take precedence because later entries in the `Map` constructor overwrite previous ones. This matters if these objects have other properties besides the ones being compared.
2. It's remotely possible that certain name/country combos could collide if they contain the `:` character. You can get fancy with how you build the entry keys, if this becomes a problem.
3. `Map` uses a hashtable behind the scenes, so the de-duplication should be reasonably fast.
4. By design, `Map` remembers input order, so the final array will reflect the same order as `allItems`, but with duplicates removed. For a different order, you'll need to sort.

Answer (score 0):

**Es6 based solution using *map()* and *filter()* method.**

**Merge two array of objects and create one removing duplicate objects**

```js
let arr1 =    [
    {
        Name: 'Roger',
        Country : 'spain'
    },
    {
        Name:'Tiger',
        Country : 'USA'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Micheal',
        Country: 'USA'
    },
];
let arr2 = [
    {
        Name: 'sachin',
        Country : 'India'
    },
    {
        Name:'Roger',
        Country : 'Spain'
    },
]
let arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2]

function mergeUniqueArray(arr, comp) {

  let unique = arr
    .map(item => item[comp])

     // store the keys of the unique objects
    .map((item, i, final) => final.indexOf(item) === i && i)

    // eliminate the duplicate keys & store unique objects
    .filter(item => arr[item]).map(item => arr[item]);
   return unique;
}

console.log(mergeUniqueArray(arr3,'Name'));
```